# Filter a dynamic table using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm trying to filter a dynamic table with AngularJS native filter in a directive.

Here is index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formation AngularJS</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="formation">

    <formation-table ng-init="nogData=[{id: 0, firstname:'Pierre', age: 31}, {id: 1, firstname:'Jean', age:10}, {id: 2, firstname:'Marie', age:5}]" headers="[{slug: 'id', name: 'ID'}, {slug: 'firstname', name: 'Firstname'}, {slug: 'age', name:'Age'}]" title="Mon tableau" nog="nogData" ></formation-table>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/03_app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the template of my directiv

```
{{title}}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="header in headers">
            <a href="" ng-click="order(header.slug)">{{header.name}}</a><br/>
            <input type="text" ng-model="filtre.id">
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in nog | filter:filtre">
        <td ng-repeat="header in headers">{{row[header.slug]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here's my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('formation', []);

app.directive('formationTable', function(){

var tableCtrl = ['$scope', "$filter", function($scope, $filter){
    $scope.order = function(name){
        var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');

        $scope.predicate = name;

        if($scope.predicate === name){
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        }
        else {
            $scope.reverse = false;
        }
        $scope.nog = orderBy($scope.nog, name, $scope.reverse);
    };
}];

return {
    scope: {
        headers : '=',
        title : '@title',
        nog : '=',
    },
    templateUrl : './templates/formationTable.html',
    controller: tableCtrl,
}
```

})

Actually, it's not working at all (whatever I type in my input doesn't change anything).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you just fiddle it out?

Comment: What do you expect to change? is the filter per column or for the whole dataset?

Comment: i'd like to do it per column, but for test reasons, I tried it to do it for whole dataset.

Comment: here the fiddle, but for some reason, nothing is apparing (i've got my table appearing on my computer, nothing on the fiddle)
https://jsfiddle.net/L7zyjj8n/8/